# How To Permanently Resize Collections Editor Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

How To Permanently Resize Collections Editor window in Visual Studio

I have searched a fair bit, but found nothing. How do i resize the size of Collection Editors window permanently. Each time i resize, it comes up small again after close/reopen. I have tried pondering with settings but could not find any reference to it.

This is the window I am referring to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKXq.jpg

Thanks
(PS i am not allowed to posts images due to being new user)

Comment: I don't think that window is resizable! It has a default size, and it always adheres to it.

Comment: Why would you want it bigger?

Comment: @Phil652 Because i am have a larger monitor and its very convenient to expand shrink a property or locate it, rather than having to scroll every time to it and then expand it. Just like the difference of coding on a 6" vs 22" screen. Plus i am working on a 4x nested collection. It becomes a pain to scroll down each time, open the sub collection window, then over and over. Thanks for your Time.

Comment: @binaryBaba i hope their is a way, i am intending to catch the window handle, and resize it by code otherwise, just when i get time. Will probably post the script here. Thanks for your time.